# Resolving bean conflicts in third-party packages

Tags: spring

I have an application, let's call it MyApp. An example of the `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
compile group: 'com.example', name: 'library'
compile .. spring-heatoas ..
```

Now, the way this `library` works is that it expects the host to give it a bean of type `ObjectMapper`. It by itself does not define an `ObjectMapper` as the configuration of the same is completely open to the host library. So basically, in the host `MyApp` I have this config:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() { ... }
}
```

Everything is fine and working, till I had the `spring-hateos` dependency. `spring-hateos` defines it's own `ObjectMapper` which goes by the name `_hal_objectMapper`. So, after adding it, I get a conflict between the two beans. I tried:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() { ... }
```

Not only does this not work, but even if it did, I guess it has the potential to break functionality as the host application can no longer configure the `ObjectMapper`. A straightforward solution obviously is to make the `library` accept a named-bean and then declare it in my host application with a `@Qualifier` annotation. But getting the library to change (and there are a couple of libraries like that) company-wide is going to be a major pain. While we are considering that solution, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation @Primary advises spring to use that annotated bean if many beans of the same type are available. This could resolve your issue.

Your code should look like this :

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper() { ... }
```

}

The problem may be now, that spring-hateos also uses this objectMapper, which is not configured as expected.

A complete solution could be, to create a child spring context.
Only for your ObjectMapper and the 3rd party bean, so that the objectMapper is not visible for the rest of you application.

How this is done depends on how you instantiate the 3rd party bean, and also where it will be used. With the provided information I cannot describe that more detailed.

You can find a good entry here :
[modularizing-configurations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/modularizing-configurations.html)

(see chapter 'Nesting @Configuration classes' or search for 'child')

Comment: While `Primary` works, using a modularized configuration seems to be absolutely the right way to go about this. It might take a while to implement this, but I feel it'll be worth it.

Comment: fwiw, I fixed this by creating a method takes in an object of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and configuring it. This had the side-effect of exposing a single `ObjectMapper` with all the required setup.